# Using Jquery with Multiple IDs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a table that shows online players in my gameserver and I'm trying to create a button that slaps that player, the script uses the players ID to slap him however my jquery script will only slap the first player in the table.

Any help is very much appreciated, here is my code

```js
function slap(){
  
    var playerid = $("#playerid").val();
  
    $.post("q3/slap.php", { playerid: playerid }, function ( data ) {
       // populate data here
    });
}
```

```html
   echo "<form><input type='hidden' id='playerid' value='$playerid'><input type=button class='actionbutton' value='Slap' onClick='slap()'></form>";
```

Comment: ID's need to be unique. You should probably switch to a class and attach an event handler to that directly in javascript / jQuery (as opposed to the `onClick()` handler).

Comment: whats your table like? and try using class instead of id.

Comment: What sets the value of `$playerid`?

Answer (score 1):

First id is unique in HTML so if you have more than one player the id is useless.

But try:

```js
function slap(playerid){
        
    $.post("q3/slap.php", { playerid: playerid }, function ( data ) {
       // populate data here
    });
}
```

```html
   echo "<form><input type=button class='actionbutton' value='Slap' onClick='slap($playerid)'></form>";
```

that should work.

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to use $playername as the variable instead? it doesn't seem to work when I change it to $playername

Answer (score 0):

`Id` is used for unique identity. Use `class` instead of `id`

```
 echo "<form><input type='hidden' class='playerid' value='$playerid'><input type=button class='actionbutton' value='Slap' onClick='slap($playerid)'></form>";
```

and in your jquery

```
 function slap(playerid){

        $.post("q3/slap.php", { playerid: playerid }, function ( data ) {
           // populate data here
        });
    }
```